# Getting a 401 error code on Postman 10.15.4 when it was working just fine on 10.13

Tags: http, postman, http-headers, www-authenticate

I have an API that I was using to obtain a JSON through a GET request. I had to first authenticate my user through POST and then GET the information from the API.

This would work just fine until the newest update (10.15.4). Now, I am still able to authenticate, but when I make the GET call, I get a 401 response code. The response headers also do NOT include WWW-Authenticate, which is what is tripping me out because apparently they SHOULD include it.

I've tried everything and I don't know what's wrong.

I followed the same logic when creating a similar service in Go using this API and that works just fine, so I don't think it has anything to do with the API or with the way the requests are being made, but maybe with Postman itself.

Comment: Pratham, the why you asked the question is out of the scope of SO, as it seems asking for debugging help. However, let's understand the question.  1) _I have an API_ Which API, custom? someone else? how code looks like? 2) _until the newest update_ What are the changes in the newer update? 3) _SHOULD include it_ why response should include that header?

Comment: 1) It is a custom API.
2) I'm not sure, I've been trying to read but I don't know which one is applicable here. https://www.postman.com/release-notes/postman-app/ 
3) THat's what everything on the internet says. a 401 is supposed to return that header everytime

Comment: Postman app updates should not affect on your code, it might me something else that creates an issue. Which auth do you use? and it would be great if you can share some code example to reproduce the issue.